# When does the "First Win of the Day" bonus exp reset?

Tags: overwatch

One way to gain exp is to play a match and win, and this is referred to as a First Win of the Day Bonus that rewards +1500 exp.

What time of the day exactly does this bonus exp reset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not too sure EXACTLY when it resets, but the only consensus I can find online is [this](http://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20744934431). It sounds like it's based on GMT, which is 7pm EST or 4pm PST etc.